# Is double vision affected by distance, direction, or light?

Tags: double-vision

**Cause of double vision:** a very very little misalligment of the two eyes because of the weakness of the muscles that moves the eyes.

It's not caused by optic neuritis or astigmatism so each eye alone sees a clear picture (6/6). Only opening the two eyes together causes double vision.

If the vision is good, why are the far objects more doubled than the near ones? Near ones are almost clear (no double vision).

If double vision is caused by the alligment of the eyes, why does double vision increase in sunlight (street) and decrease in my home?

Why double vision happens when I look left only?

**I'm not seeking for a medical advice as I already went to a doctor and receiving treatment.** I just need an explanation for those phenomena. What's happening inside the body? Or are these just hallucinations?